# show data in readonly format

Tags: php, javascript, kohana

views

edit.php

```
<div class="detail">
<?php echo Form::label("first_name", "First Name"); ?>
<?php echo Form::input("first_name", $userdetails->first_name); ?>
</div>
<div class="detail">    
<?php echo Form::label("last_name", "Last Name"); ?>
<?php echo Form::input("last_name", $userdetails->last_name); ?>
</div>
<div class="detail1" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
<?php echo Form::label("birth_date", "Date of Birth"); ?>
<?php echo Form::input("birth_date", $userdetails->birth_date); ?>
</div>
```

The above edit.php is rendering the html form in web page in field editable mode.I want to make that field as readonly.I want to create a link in name of "edit" above this form and by clicking the edit link,the readonly should look as editable and possible to edit.How to do this using kohana.

Comment: [**RTFM**](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/Form#input). You can pass in a third argument to `Form::input()` that is an array of attributes. Add `array('disabled' => 'disabled')` and you'll be fine. I've never used Kohana before and found this in 30 seconds. You are _lazy_

Comment: That will require some JavaScript. I strongly suggest you go away and learn how to do some of this stuff, which is what you should be doing if you're new to it